# Namespace function defaults to global first

Tags: php, namespaces

I know that by default a function call will default first to the current namespace then if not found will check the global namespace. Is there any way to alter this behavior, perhaps using the "use something as somethingelse" so that it only checks the global namespace?

One hard rule is that I cannot modify the function calls within the namespace.

For example in the global namespace

```
function get_something() {
  return 1;
}
```

File in question

```
namespace new;

$a = get_something();

function get_something() {
  return 2;
}
```

I want $a to be evaluated to 1. Is there a way to do this without updating all the $a = get_something() references in the namespaced file?

Comment: _Why_ you write a function, when you don't want to use it? And why you use the same function names, when you see, that you cannot handle the collision the way you like? (Naming namespaced functions like other functions from the global scope is a bad habit anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$a = \get_something();
```

to explicitly target the global namespace.

Comment: that was the only requirement of what I cannot do

Comment: You _cannot_ add a blackslash?!? Oo

Comment: I can't add the backslash because it is someone elses library that I'm trying to wrap their functions with my own by just namespacing theirs. This works great unless they call into their own functions.